# Filter pandas dataframe for rows with a specific date

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am new to python (I have used R in the past). I have a pandas data frame with one column containing dates. I would like to filter for observations occurring on one specific date.

```
## Create the pandas DataFrame with column named purchase-date 
data = ['2023-11-25', '2023-11-24', '2023-11-25', '2023-11-23'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['purchase-date']) 

## convert string format to datetime 
df['purchase-date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchase-date']).dt.date 

## Attempt 1: Try setting purchase date as the index and using .loc 
df.set_index('purchase-date') 
df.loc['2023-11-24':'2023-11-24'] 

## Attempt 2: Filter without making purchase date the index 
df[(df['purchase-date'] > '2023-11-23') & (df['purchase-date'] < '2023-11-25')]
```

This is the error I got:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is related to the fact that you're trying to compare a `datetime.date` object with a string in your second attempt.

**filter based on dates, you need to compare `datetime.date` objects :**

```
import pandas as pd


data = ['2023-11-25', '2023-11-24', '2023-11-25', '2023-11-23']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['purchase-date'])


df['purchase-date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchase-date']).dt.date

# Filter without making purchase date the index
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-11-23').date()
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-11-25').date()

filtered_df = df[(df['purchase-date'] > start_date) & (df['purchase-date'] < end_date)]

print(filtered_df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
m = df["purchase-date"].between("2023-11-24", "2023-11-24")
print(df[m])
```

Prints:

```
  purchase-date
1    2023-11-24
```

Or:

```
print(df[df["purchase-date"] == "2023-11-24"])
```

---

The dataframe was created using:

```
data = ["2023-11-25", "2023-11-24", "2023-11-25", "2023-11-23"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["purchase-date"])
df["purchase-date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["purchase-date"])
```